# So how does Unity finds that Start() and Update methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oop

I couldn't understand how Unity manages to call MonoBehavior's [Start()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) and Update() methods. These methods are neither an overridden method nor an interface implementation but still somehow get called at the right time as soon you include them in your class - if I inherit class from MonoBehaviour and create Start() method, it will be highlighted immediately and called at first frame.

I can see use of Reflection to do that but all I read about reflection mentions that it is slow and I'd expect Unity to avoid such "known slow" approaches.

So how does Unity finds that Start() method in each class? Is there some other OOP concept outside inheritance that is implemented to suppotr that?

Comment: it is not reflection but a messaging system that is more performant and precompiled ... but yeah for your understanding it basically works more or less similar to reflection but on a different level (being invoked from the underlying c++ engine ... remember that the c# you implement is just an API level sitting on top of that)

Comment: "OOP" is much less relevant, and important, than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good point in comments, that Unity works much different, than regular C# frameworks do. Especially, when you use IL2CPP scripting backend. Every single line of code, you've written in the C#, will be handled by Unity build system itself while building. There is no problem for Unity to modify your code(and Unity always does it a lot while building) to make some entry points for any private/protected and whatever else code. Without using widely known C# reflection, but just by adding/modifying required code.

PS. One common way to make such performant calls is a [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), variations of which, probably, used in Unity messages. It also used in regular C# in foreach cycles, async/await and other places.